# How to handle a angular js dialog box using rails+capybara for automation testing using cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, automation, cucumber, capybara

Currently I am working on an application which use angular JS.
In the application, there is flow, where on clicking a button, a dialog box will be displayed with some fields in it.

I am trying to enter some value in the fields inside the dialog box. But when ever the dialog box opens I am getting error 'unexpected alert open'.

Can any one help me in this?
You can also mail me on this. Mail Id: abhisekearly@gmail.com

Comment: What driver are you using? "Unexpected alert open" would tend to refer to a system alert box being opened but you don't mention that in your description - are you sure nothing triggers a system alert box?

Comment: Hi Tom, I am using Chromedriver 2.9.248315 on windows 7. Code that triggers the dialog box: find(:css, "div.editSectionNav > button.btn.ng-scope").click

Comment: The element mentioned above is a button kind of element. Clicking it, a dialog box appears which contains some field. I just need to put some value in the fields and click on 'OK' button in the dialog box. Please let me know, if you need any additional info on this.

Comment: You didn't answer what driver you're using with capybara, is it selenium? If so the "Unexpected alert open" means that a system alert, confirm or prompt is opening - Is it a prompt box that opens when you trigger the button?? (that would only have one field though and you keep saying fields).  If not, does a system confirm box get opened when you press the 'OK' button? (possibly saying something like 'Are you sure?' )  Maybe you should just add the code where the error is occuring and the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Sorry Tom, if my comments are not clear. Back to your questions. Yes, it is selenium. I am getting a popup kind of dialog box. Where it have some editable fields, with 2 buttons i.e OK and CANCEL. I tried the below code but nothing works. Codes to Accept Alert: page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept,                                       Code to Open Popup and do action there:                                       main = page.driver.browser.window_handles.first, popup = page.driver.browser.switch_to.popup.alert.last, page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(popup)...but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok -- I'm still not 100% sure that what you're seeing is a system prompt modal - since you keep saying "fields" while a system prompt modal can only have one field but here goes.

For a system modal you need to call accept_prompt and pass it a block that will trigger the prompt to open

```
accept_prompt(with: "the test to enter into the field in the prompt) do
  click_button("button that opens the prompt modal")
end
```

So in cucumber this could be implemented something like

```
When /^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)" and confirm with "([^"]*)"$/ do |button, response|
  accept_prompt(with: response) do
    click_button(button)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I have discussed this with my development team here. As per them it is a Popup modal/dialog box. Here is the code for they have used to create the popup:  Class = ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-front ui-dialog-buttons ui-draggable ui-resizable. this they have put in div tag. They used angular js here. It contains 7-8 fields and 2 buttons i.e. OK and Cancel button. Here your code will take value for only one field right?I don't think it will work in my case. Anyway I will try this code provided and reply you the result.

Comment: Ok -- that would be a jQuery-UI modal, not a system modal (system modals are opened by calling window.alert, confirm, or prompt from JS) - so maybe a system modal is appearing after you submit the jQuery-UI modal?  I don't really know -- as I said in the comments on the question - it may be best if you post your test code, where the errors is occurring in that code,  and the stacktrace for the error in your question

Comment: Hi Tom, Sorry for replying so late. I tried the steps you mentioned but it doesn't work. I won't be able to share my code as it is confidential (Hope you understand). Is there any way to handle the jQuery-UI? or can you direct me to any site where i can get the more details on handling the jQuery-UI. It will be a great help if you can help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you can't provide any example of the code thats actually happening there is nothing further I can help with.